# why some websites redirects to it self when use in iframe

Tags: html, redirect, iframe

I have this page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>my title</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.shereno.com"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

but when execute this page after 1 second page redirect to `http://www.shereno.com`

can you use this url in iframe whitout redirect?

Comment: Most likely this site uses a “frame breaking” JavaScript, and that means the owner of that site does not _want_ you to display it inside an iframe on your page …

Comment: but i want find a way to display this site in iframe in my website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML5 use the `sandbox` attribute to disalow `allow-top-navigation` which allows the document to break out of the frame by navigating the top-level window. We define the `sandbox` attribute and leave `allow-top-navigation` out!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>my title</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" src="http://www.shereno.com"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is very very good. Thank you very much my friend. Do you know Why this site redirects?

Comment: Its hard to figure it out, since he uses minimized and scrambled script resources.